# Dynamic memory allocation in COBOL

Tags: dynamic-memory-allocation, cobol

I have a common C function that I want to call from C, Fortran and COBOL. It  fetches x bytes of data from a database and places it in a char pointer supplied to it. My example below fetches 1024 bytes, but in the real situation I want to be able to fetch much larger chunks of data than 1024 bytes as well, hence the dynamic memory allocation.

```
void fetch_data(char *fetched)
{
    static struct {unsigned long data_length; char some_data[1024];} a_struct;
    // Fetch data into a_struct.
    memcpy(fetched, &(a_struct.some_data), 1024);
}
```

I was able to call this function successfully from C.

```
char *mydata;
mydata = malloc(1024);
fetch_data(mydata);
// Do something with the data.
free(mydata);
```

I was also able to call this function successfully from Fortran.

```
INTEGER*4, ALLOCATABLE :: MYDATA(:)
ALLOCATE(MYDATA(1024))
CALL FETCH_DATA(MYDATA)    
// Do something with the data.
DEALLOCATE(MYDATA)
```

But how do I allocate and deallocate dynamic memory in COBOL? I have been unable to find built-in functions/procedures for this purpose.

I also don't see an alternative where C could handle the allocation and deallocation for Fortran and COBOL, as they need to access the data outside C.

Comment: Your final paragraph mentions Fortran.  If you want to know about C-interoperable dynamic memory in Fortran as well as COBOL it may be better to ask a separate question (although this has been covered elsewhere).

Comment: Additionally, may be irrelevant but I hope do you check if `mydata` is NULL after `malloc()`

Comment: COBOL and Fortran are really different, you should ask separately unless you need only to help with COBOL.

Comment: I did ask separately. This question is about COBOL. I just wanted to point out that it needs to be compatible with Fortran as well, as that might influence the answers I get.

Comment: No experience with Cobol, but along this line...? https://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/master/manual/html/mmref/lang.html https://open-cobol.sourceforge.io/cgi-bin/gnucobol/doc/tip/verbs/allocate.md

Comment: Which COBOL compiler and version are you using? Any that conform to the 2002 standard will have ALLOCATE and FREE as statements rather than functions. Earlier compilers will have called routines in supplemental materials.

Comment: I second a request for the environment. For IBM z/OS, Enterprise COBOL 6.2 finally added the ALLOCATE/FREE statements so you don't have to call the LE CEE routines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you've only talked about "COBOL" without specifying any actual implementation I assume you mean "standard COBOL".

This could mean COBOL85 - which doesn't have this feature but allows you to just define `DATA-FOR-C PIC X(1024)` and pass this as reference (COBOL85 actually doesn't specify anything about calling into C space but this should work with most if not all COBOL implementations). Note: This is actually more a detail of Acorns answer.

If you want to use real dynamic memory allocation and you mean standard COBOL - no problem with COBOL 2002 as it introduced the statements `ALLOCATE` and `FREE` (Note: this is actually the detail of the comments from roygvib and Rick):

```
77 pointer-variable  USAGE POINTER.
77 address-holder    PIC X BASED.

ALLOCATE variable-number CHARACTERS RETURNING pointer-variable
SET ADDRESS OF address-holder TO pointer-variable
CALL "fetch_data" USING address-holder
PERFORM stuff
FREE pointer-variable
```

If you don't use a COBOL implementation that support these statements you'd have to use the implementor specific routines (normally via `CALL`) to get/release the memory.

- MicroFocus/NetCOBOL (see answer of Rick): `CBL_ALLOC_MEM`/`CBL_FREE_MEM[2]`
- ACUCOBOL: `M$ALLOC`/`M$FREE`
- IBM: `CEEGTST`
- any COBOL compiler and runtime that allows to directly call C functions (which *may* adds additional needs as specifying the appropriate CALL-CONVENTION for those): `malloc`/`free`
- ... see your implementor's manual ...

Answer (score 6):

One example with a very old compiler (Micro Focus COBOL v3.2.50). Much of this is taken directly from the supplemental materials. And since I didn't have an equally old C compiler available, I included a COBOL program as a subtitute.

```
   program-id. dynam.
   data division.
   working-storage section.
   1 ptr pointer.
   1 mem-size pic x(4) comp-5 value 1024.
   1 flags pic x(4) comp-5 value 1.
   1 status-code pic x(2) comp-5.
   linkage section.
   1 mem pic x(1024).
   procedure division.
       call "CBL_ALLOC_MEM" using ptr
           by value mem-size flags
         returning status-code
       if status-code not = 0
           display "memory allocation failed"
           stop run
       else
           set address of mem to ptr
       end-if

       call "fetch_data" using mem
       display mem

       call "CBL_FREE_MEM" using mem
         returning status-code
       if status-code not = 0
           display "memory deallocation failed"
           stop run
       else
           set address of mem to null
       end-if
       stop run
       .
   end program dynam.

   program-id. "fetch_data".
   data division.
   working-storage section.
   1 some-struct pic x(1024) value all "abcd".
   linkage section.
   1 mem pic x(1024).
   procedure division using mem.
       move some-struct to mem
       exit program
       .
   end program "fetch_data".
```

The display (trimmed) is:

```
 abcdabcdabcdabcd...(for 1024 characters total)
```

Maybe that will be of some help.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not need the entire data in memory, then consider working chunk-by-chunk: allocate fixed-size storage in COBOL, fetch a chunk into it using the C function, work with it and loop to continue with the next chunk. This way you can avoid allocating dynamic memory altogether.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Z or using Gnu Cobol you can simply call malloc():

```
        CALL "malloc" USING BY VALUE MEM-SIZE
             RETURNING MEM-PTR.

        CALL "free" USING BY VALUE MEM-PTR.
```